# Email Template Library in Java

Tags: java, email, email-templates

I know that there is a library called [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) to create Email templates for Java. Do you think this library is suitable to use in enterprise projects? Is there any other libraries to create email template for java?

Comment: can you suggest a tutorial  on the freemarker to create java mail templates for java

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Freemarker works well, and is very powerful. [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) has a simpler syntax, is somewhat less powerful, and is a lot more forgiving wrt. nulls (variables not being populated).

I've used both, and Velocity is very easy to get started with. Freemarker (despite its stricter implementation) offers a lot more in terms of 'correctness' and facilities.

Answer (score 3):

yes, it is. For the sake of completeness there are other compelling libraries like:

- apache velocity
- string templace

Answer (score 3):

A number of years ago I've written an application for sending invoice notifications. I used Velocity to create the actual contents of the e-mails. The transport was provided by James, the e-mail server by Apache. This application sends out 10s of thousands of personalised e-mails each day.

Velocity did not give me any problems, but having had some experience with FreeMarker, I would probably pick FreeMarker now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of [Pebble](http://mitchellbosecke.com/pebble) templating engine which I think is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, there are many other [template engines](http://java-source.net/open-source/template-engines) that you can use, and not only for email. In most projects that I've worked on, Velocity was used and when it wasn't Velocity, it was Freemarker.

Answer (score 1):

Another option you may want to look into (though probably not) is to use JSP, if you are in a Servlet environment. For the most part, I wouldn't recommend this since it's really quite a lot of up front work to get this set up.

However, this was a useful solution in our environment, where we have a bunch of web developers who are already familiar with JSP syntax and custom tags. It was nice to be able to have them work on the e-mail contents directly without having to learn another templating language (though I'm sure FreeMarker probably isn't that hard to learn). This approach also allows us to re-use some of our custom tags in e-mail content.

Answer (score 1):

Before I started doing my email templating, I thought I will ask my gFriend, and I came across the idea of using the JSP engine for templating (if you're in a servlet environment). I found the idea original and perfect for my needs since I'm under GAE and adding jar to GAE is a very costly decision (impact on performance)

And how I came to that link (the original idea) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/458088/2033675

So I put a link to how to do it [Suggestions for Java email templating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456148/suggestions-for-java-email-templating/20847683#20847683)

naturally in case someone will have the same constrains as I do.

Best

Answer (score 0):

In the enterprise sector many people haveuse tools like sonar or PMD to have a look on code complexity. I don't know if one of these supports any templating library. However, the level of complexity of templates I've reviewed in the wild was on a high niveau, I'd really like to prevent in my code. I tried to refactor some of them, and even though I made some success the results were never satisfying. Some days ago I refactored a 2kLoC template to 150 lines of template code and about 1.5kLoC logic in a new java class using [Snippetory](http://www.jproggy.org/snippetory). Of course this left still some work to match out metrics, but now it's possible to achieve maintainable code. Snippetory templates provide a great separation of concerns by moving the data binding logic out of the template. As a bonus the template gets more re-useable. On the other hand the binding between logic and code requires some code, too. In the end te amount of code didn't change much, but readability increased dramatically.

For the enterprise business I'd recomment Snippetory.