# How can I easily use a JSP page as an email template using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, email, jsp

My emails will need to be HTML anyway and I don't want to introduce another HTML generation mechanism (e.g. Velocity) into my project if I don't have to. It would be nice if image references in the generated HTML could be converted into attachments automatically.

Comment: See:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20847683/527533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fire a HTTP request on it.

```
InputStream response = new URL("http://localhost/context/page.jsp").openStream();
```

If you want to let the JSP access the same session as the current request, do so:

```
String url = "http://localhost/context/page.jsp";
String jsessionid = "jsessionid=" + request.getSession().getId();
InputStream response = new URL(url + ";" + jsessionid).openStream();
```

Needless to say that JSP is not entirely the *right* tool for the job. JSP is a webbased **view** technology, not a standalone **template** technology. Look, you need to fire a whole HTTP request just to get its output. While not necessarily expensive, this is hacky.

Comment: Hmm. Why don't you think that a JSP is the right tool for the job? Essentially I need to generate HTML and thats what JSP's are all about right?

Comment: I got this working using request.getRequestDispatcher() and Springs MockHttpServletResponse to capture the output. Thanks for the help.