# Only html of jsp page are rendered , jsp tags displays as it as

Tags: jsp, servlets

While trying to render jsp template for email, i only get html displayed properly, jsp tags comes as it is..

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(new File(emailTemplateJSP)), writer);
message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
message.setContent(writer.toString(), "text/html;charset=utf-8");
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");]
```

Here, only html portion of "emailTemplateJSP" is displayed in inbox. Still scratching my head..

Comment: output in email is something like Hello World!<%=request.getAttribute("name")%>. Jsp tags displays as it is..

Comment: Kindly check the extension of the file, may be its `.html`. To parse jsp scriplets it needs to be `.jsp`.

Comment: it is jsp..just checkd

Comment: I hope you are not directly running your jsp from browser instead of launching web app through application servers like tomcat, glassfish.

Comment: yes, i am trying to use jsp page as a template for sending emails..so..do you know how can we fix this?

Comment: Yeah, that will obviously not work. Use a template engine like velocity or freemarker. Or you can do something like the solution proposed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434053/how-can-i-easily-use-a-jsp-page-as-an-email-template-using-spring), or one of the options discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456148/suggestions-for-java-email-templating).

Comment: I have a html template for email which i have to populate and send as a body of email..what might be the best approach to do this?

Comment: Like I said, use a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending the file directly via your code by email and looking at the email in your inbox of your email client.

In order for the .jsp file to be properly parsed it must be processed by a servlet engine like Tomcat, Glassfish, WebLogic, etc…

.jsp file are processed by the servlet engine and then the proper HTML is rendered in the view to be displayed in a browser or email client inbox

So your code needs to be running in a servlet engine in this case and your view file (.jsp) processed and HTML produced before sending the resulting HTML file via email.

Comment: So..is there any solution besides template engine?

Comment: Template engine?? JSP files are designed to be run on a servlet engine and have to be processed by a servlet engine. Perhaps JSP is not the best solution for you email template, not sure where you are running this code.

Comment: i get email something like this Hello World <%=request.getAttribute("name")%> from this code in servlet

Comment: Do not use JSP templates for this. You could get this to work however I  normally use a templating library such as Apache Velocity to build email content. http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html#What_is_Velocity

Answer (score 0):

What you do now, is that you read the file as byte stream and you don't let servlet container to translate the jsp tags to html. You need to create a call to the required page and then copy it's byte as you do now.

You better use a tool rather than reading file directly specially if the jsp will require parameters.

Below is a link for a tutorial about an excellent tool called apache HttpClient(part of jakarta commons project). It's very simple and will save you the headache of sockets handling.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/