# Using seam:mail in Message Driven Bean

Tags: java, email, jsf, seam, template-engine

I'm familiar with JSF and have the requirement for automatically creating e-mails. I like the idea of seam:mail of templating e-mails in a JSF-style and also use JSF components:

```
<m:message>
  <m:from name="Peter" address="peter@example.com" />
  <m:to name="#{person.firstname} #{person.lastname}">#{person.address}</m:to>
  <m:subject>Try out Seam!</m:subject>
  <m:body>
    <p><h:outputText value="Dear #{person.firstname}" />,</p>
    <p>You can try out Seam by visiting 
    <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>.</p>
    <p>Regards,</p>
    <p>Pete</p>
  </m:body>
</m:message>
```

As far as I understood the [Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/mail.html#d0e20792), especially this snippet (shortened),

> So, now you have your email template, how do you go about sending it? Well, at the end of rendering the m:message the mailSession is called to send the email, so all you have to do is ask Seam to render the view,

```
@In(create=true) private Renderer renderer;

public void send()
{
   renderer.render("/simple.xhtml");
   facesMessages.add("Email sent successfully");
}
```

this is invoked in a common JSF (Facelet) page. Is there any chance to do this in a Message Driven Bean? Or should I head to other templating engines? see [Suggestions for Java email templating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456148)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK [Message Driven Beans are for receiving messages](http://www.roseindia.net/ejb/MessageDrivenBeans.shtml). I think it does not make much sence with your *requirement for automatically creating e-mails*.

Anyways, [this Seam tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/1.1.5.GA/reference/en/html/jms.html) tells you about sending and receiving JMS messages with seam. Maybe it serves for your purpose, whatever it is.

Comment: I want an asynchronous processing. If an event occurs, one (or multiple) JMS message are created put into the Queue. The receiver(s) get the JMS message, prepare the HTML email and send it by SMTP.

Comment: Then my second link is the most useful, if any :)

Comment: Second link says `Message-driven beans may even be Seam components, in which case it is possible to inject other event and application scoped Seam components.` ... this looks very promising and I will test it!