# How to get the result of a JSP in a java method?

Tags: email, jsp, jakarta-mail, portal

I am working on a restaurant web portal which will send periodic emails to the registered users such as changes in menu, discounts and offers, birthday wishes etc.

Here is how I am doing it-

1. I create a JSP page with the HTML formatting. This page accepts certain parameters that will customize the page.
2. The MailDaemon scans the db and upon a certain trigger will make a GET request to the JSP.
3. The returned JSP represents the final mail content which is then sent using the JavaMail API.

My questions are these -

1. Do I really need to make a GET request? Or can I obtain the JSP result directly in my Daemon class?
2. Does my approach have any drawbacks? Any better solutions (architecturally speaking)
3. Any other templating solutions for the job?

Comment: See my JSP->Email code sample here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20847683/527533

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's possible to buffer a response from your JSP using [`javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher#include`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) by wrapping original response in [`javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponseWrapper.html) (in case your `MailDaemon` is a servlet)
2. Your approach is OK. Though it'll be easier to leverage another templating engine.
3. [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/). These two are not tied to web, so you can easily use them without servlet container.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're using the JSP as a templating engine to generate the body of an HTML email. If you want to keep using JSPs for that, I don't think there's a better solution than making a GET request to get the generated HTML.

But you could also use an embeddable templating engine like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html) or [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) to generate the HTML to a String, directly from the mail daemon.