# Using JSP as template parsing engine - security concerns

Tags: java, jsp

I have a question regarding the JSP template parsing engine.

What I'm building at the moment is something which allows clients to write their own templates in JSP (inside a textarea on a webpage) which can then be used for email, landing pages, etc.

Can JSP tags / scriptlets be used to access data other than that made available through ${variables} which I set in the HttpRequest ?

In other words, would giving clients direct access to a JSP template engine pose a security risk, and if so, can I turn on / off certain JSP tags that poses a security risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSPs are **tightly bound** to HTTP request lifecycle. JSPs are directly compiled into Java classes implementing `HttpServlet`. With scriptlets you would introduce pretty obvious security hole into your system (JSP authors can write and execute arbitrary Java code on your server).

**TL;DR** JSPs are pretty bad choice for your use-case. Use templating engine which is not based purely on HTTP requests (String Template, Freemarker, ...).

Comment: If I disable scriptlets, would there be other potential security holes?
From what I understand, if there are no scriptlets, the only thing left to access are variables that are explicitly set in the HttpRequest, if they aren't explicitly set, they can't be used?

Comment: And how are you compiling and calling JSPs? AFAIK there is no standard way how to manually compile JSP and there is no standard way how to call them without request context... They are managed and called by servlet container. Using JSPs to render e-mails would be an ugly hack in my opinion.

Comment: I've already written a prototype that can parse JSP, it basically intercepts the output and writes it to a StringBuffer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456148/suggestions-for-java-email-templating/20847683#20847683

Comment: String Template actually looks decent, going to try that instead of JSPs. Thanks Pavel.

Comment: If would like to have a background task for sending e-mails, you won't be able to do that as you won't have access to request dispatcher. This approach would be a no-go for me.

Comment: Also there are more things to consider... there are lots of things on a request. If you are using Struts or Spring you would be able to tamper with the framework. That can end again in running arbitrary code. Then there are directives and tags which can be misused. E.g. you can call `<%@ include >` to include custom file in your template (e.g. application config :)).